# How to write custom Callback for saving the model at every epoch if validation accuracy is improved from previous epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, deep-learning, tf.keras

Below is my custom callback function that I wrote but it doesn't work:

```
class bestval(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.history={'loss': [],'acc': [],'val_loss': [],'val_acc': []}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        #appending val_acc in history
        if logs.get('val_acc', -1) != -1:
            self.history['val_acc'].append(logs.get('val_acc'))
        # Trying to compare current epoch val_acc with all the values in self.history['val_acc']
        if logs.get('val_acc')> [i for i in self.history['val_acc']]:
            filepath="model_save/weights-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.4f}.hdf5"
            # Saving the model using TF built-in callback 
            checkpoint = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, 
            monitor='val_acc',  verbose=1, mode='auto')
bestobj= bestval()
```

Fitting the model:

```
model.fit(xtr,ytr, epochs=4, validation_data=(xte,yte), batch_size=128, callbacks=[bestobj])
```

When I run the above I get the below error:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I know I am doing something stupid but I don't know how to fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add your full error trace.

Comment: You need to use `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` directly by passing it to the `model.fit()` arguments. Use `save_best_only=True` to store only the "best" weights according to quantity being monitored. Please read the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is in following line, you are trying to compare a value with a list.
`if logs.get('val_acc')> [i for i in self.history['val_acc']]:`

try,
`for i in self.history['val_acc']:
         if logs.get('val_acc')>i:
               #your code`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did make changes in the code which cleared the error however it didn't run my code after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if logs.get('val_acc') > [i for i in self.history['val_acc']]
```

Use

```
if any(logs.get('val_acc')> val for val in self.history['val_acc'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).